# iOS / Firebase: Using queryStartingAtValue and NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 return no results

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to query for the latest objects with a timestamp that has not been created by the server. Unfortunately the observer does not fire on new messages as intended when using `NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970`, even though there are no error messages:

```
    let timestampQueryValue = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000

    let messagesRef = self.ref.child("messages").child(chatId)

    messagesRef
        .queryOrderedByChild("timestamp")
        .queryLimitedToLast(500)
        .queryStartingAtValue(timestampQueryValue) // if commented out, new messages show up alongside older ones
        .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in

        // ...
    })
```

I am using `Firebase 3.4.0`.

Comment: The observer doesn't fire as intended when using `NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970` or `NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000`?

Comment: When using `NSDate().timeInterv‌​alSince1970 * 1000` as shown in the code.

Comment: And just to be sure, is there a `timestamp` field on the objects?

Comment: Ok, I think I found the reason: The timestamp created by `NSDate().timeInterv‌​‌​alSince1970 * 1000` is one hour ahead compared to the server time. That's the reason why no new messages show up. But using `FIRServerValue.timestamp()` in `queryStartingAtValue` throws an error. Any idea how to deal with this issue?